# Which one is the correct preposition?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

> - David is going **through** the ladder.
> - David is going **from** the ladder.
> - David is going **by** the ladder.

Which one is the correct preposition?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to say. What in fact is David doing? --is he moving from the ladder to some other place (*going **away** from*), is he moving between the ladder and the wall it's leaning against (*going **under** the ladder*), is he climbing by means of the ladder (*going **up** the ladder*), or is he doing something else?

Comment: We can also say "David is **climbing** the ladder".

Comment: *going through = entering, examining, searching,* etc. More context is required.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of a **ladder**, one can :

> get **on** a ladder
>   go **by** a ladder
>   go **from** a ladder
>   go **under** a ladder
>   get **off** a ladder
>   go **behind** a ladder
>   go **in front** of a ladder
>   stand **beside** a ladder
>   come **down** a ladder

To **go by** a ladder is to walk by it.
To **go from** a ladder is to use the ladder as a **point of origin**.

but one can not :

> go **through** a ladder
>   get **into** a ladder

because one can not physically **enter** a ladder.

[NB: **going under** a ladder can be considered **bad luck** in some cultures]

Comment: Despite the fact that the question is very unclear, you've given almost all possible things you can do with a ladder. Well said.